# Using Jsoup to parse text between two tags

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

Assume i want to get the text "abcd" in a html page as follows:

```
<div class="box">
abcd
<select class="selectbox">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I can just get all the texts inside the div..my java code:

```
Elements list = doc.select(".box");
String item = list.get(0).text();
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.get(0).ownText();`

from [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29):

> **ownText** -
>   Gets the text owned by this element only; does not get the combined text of all children.

Comment: bravo! it's so easy ;)